# Get edges between two sets of vertices in R without using adjacency matrix

Tags: r, igraph

I'm searching for an efficient way to get (the count of) all the edges between two sets of vertices in R. I've got a large graph with two (large) sets of vertices and I would like to get all the edges that start from set1 and end in set2 or vice versa. set1 and set2 and mutually exclusive. Graph is not directed, so i don't want to have duplicate edges. I'm hoping to avoid using the adjacency matrix but if adjacency matrix is the most computationally/memory-wise efficient way, then it can't be helped. (I know how to do it using adjacency matrix)

```
require(igraph)
require(dplyr)
graph <- make_full_graph(7)
V(graph)$name <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G")
set1 <- V(graph)[name %in% c("A", "C")]
set2 <- V(graph)[name %in% c("E", "D")]

#desired Output
    A -- E
    C -- E
    A -- D
    C -- D
#desired Output
    4  #number of edges
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I this case you can use the `%--%` operators when selecting edges. It will subset edges where going from one set of vertices to another. You can do

```
E(graph)[set1 %--% set2]
# [1] A--D A--E C--D C--E
```

You can find this documented on the `?"igraph-es-indexing"` help page.

Comment: Seem I was looking at all the wrong functions in igraph. Many thanks.